# Is NSManagedObjecte subclasses are the primary model classes in your project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

When you want to create a to-do app for instance, and you have a "lists" model that you created (a simple ObjC class of NSObject) that will have its properties @name @numberOfToDos etc, So if until now before using core data I saved it by just new/file/objective c class, so now I will need to first create a model map, create entities and attributes, and then select them and go editor/create NSManagedObjecte subclass (or something like this)?

if yes, are those the only classes that represent this models?

Comment: If you want to use Core Data and do not have a lot of experience, I would highly suggest creating a new project with the Master-Detail template. It will establish everything you need to get started with your models. You should also never be explicitly subclassing NSManagedObject. Create your model(s) and then create your managed objects based on the Entities, which will end up subclassing NSManagedObject.

Comment: Yes, probably in this case, though in bigger apps you will often have some core data model and some plain model (not persisted, or not in the same way). Look at using mogenerator too.